# Validate array, then return it

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to get more into arrays.

Im passing an array to a class which should validate the input ant convert it into uppercase.

```
class Input {

public function clean(array $variable)
{
    $count = 0;
    $input = array();
    foreach($variable as $row)
    {
        $variable = strtoupper(trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($row))));
        $input[$count]['input'] = $variable;
        $count++;
    }

    return $input;
}
}

$input = new Input;

$array = array('John', 'Marie', 'Alice');
$input->clean($array);
```

What is the way to validate the entire array and return each result, so i could echo it out?

Thanks!

P.S. is this a good approach? Or should I rather keep on validating every variable separately?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $input->clean($array);
var_dump($result);
```